# Boolean checking in the 'if' condition

Tags: java, coding-style

Which one is better Java coding style?

```
boolean status = true;
if (!status) {
    //do sth
} else {
    //do sth
}
```

**or:**

```
if (status == false) {
    //do sth
} else {
    //do sth
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Former, of course. Latter is redundant, and only goes to show that you haven't understood the concept of booleans very well.

One more suggestion: Choose a different name for your `boolean` variable. As per [this Java style guide](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html):

> **is prefix should be used for boolean variables and methods.**
>
> `isSet`, `isVisible`, `isFinished`,
>   `isFound`, `isOpen`
>
> This is the naming convention for
>   `boolean` methods and variables used
>   by Sun for the Java core packages.
>
> Using the `is` prefix solves a common
>   problem of choosing bad boolean names
>   like `status` or `flag`. `isStatus` or
>   `isFlag` simply doesn't fit, and the
>   programmer is forced to chose more
>   meaningful names.
>
> Setter methods for `boolean` variables
>   must have set prefix as in:
>
> `void setFound(boolean isFound);`
>
> There are a few alternatives to the
>   `is` prefix that fits better in some
>   situations. These are `has`, `can` and
>   `should` prefixes:
>
> ```
> boolean hasLicense();
> boolean canEvaluate();
> boolean shouldAbort = false;
> ```

Comment: Try `good_status` or `fair_weather_status` or `status_known` or `status_unknown` or even `status_malus__vana_salus__semper_dissolubilis`. :)

Answer (score 29):

I would suggest that you do:

```
if (status) {
    //positive work
} else {
    // negative work
}
```

The `==` tests, while obviously redundant,  also run the risk of a single `=` typo which would result in an assignment.

Answer (score 10):

If you look at the alternatives on this page, of course the first option looks better and the second one is just more verbose.  But if you are looking through a large class that someone else wrote, that verbosity can make the difference between realizing right away what the conditional is testing or not.

One of the reasons I moved away from Perl is because it relies so heavily on punctuation, which is much slower to interpret while reading.

I know I'm outvoted here, but I will almost always side with more explicit code so others can read it more accurately.  Then again, I would never use a boolean variable called "status" either.  Maybe isSuccess or just success, but "status" being true or false does not mean anything to the casual reader intuitively.  As you can tell, I'm very into code readability because I read so much code others have written.

Comment: agree with `status` being a horrible name, but `!s` is idiomatic in the C-derived languages for testing for false-hood.

Comment: @lijie: While "!" is unambiguous, it is simply harder to notice when scanning code than " == false".  Given that it completely negates the conditional after it, to me it's worth the extra typing.

Comment: FWIW (probably not a lot), I'd point out in code reviews that  "explicit comparisons of a boolean with literal true/false" are redundant and non-idiomatic.  I agree that the name "status" is not clear. If the name was "isGood" would you still object to ```if (!isGood)``` ?

Answer (score 7):

The first one, or `if (status) { /*second clause*/ } else { /* first clause */ }`

**EDIT**

If the second form is really desired, then `if (false == status) <etc>`, while uglier, is probably safer (wrt typos).

Comment: +1 for (false == status), which also gives guidance for the `if (0==i)` question not asked

Comment: I'd definitely reject code using Yoda-conditions.  Code should be readable.  No-one says "here we check if false is the status" in English.

Answer (score 5):

It really also depends on how you name your variable.

When people are asking "which is better practice" - this implicitly implies that both are correct, so it's just a matter of which is easier to read and maintain.

If you name your variable "status" (which is the case in your example code), I would much prefer to see

`if(status == false)  // if status is false`

On the other hand, if you had named your variable isXXX (e.g. isReadableCode), then the former is more readable. consider:

```
if(!isReadable) { // if not readable
  System.out.println("I'm having a headache reading your code");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The former. The latter merely adds verbosity.

Answer (score 3):

The first one. But just another point, the following would also make your code more readable:

```
if (!status) {
    // do false logic
} else {
    // do true logic
}
```

Note that there are extra spaces between `if` and the `(`, and also before the `else` statement.

**EDIT**

As noted by @Mudassir, if there is **NO** other shared code in the method using the logic, then the better style would be:

```
if (!status) {
    // do false logic
}

// do true logic
```

Answer (score 2):

My personal feeling when it comes to reading

```
if(!status) : if not status

if(status == false) : if status is false
```

if you are not used to !status reading. I see no harm doing as the second way.

if you use "active" instead of status I thing if(!active) is more readable

Answer (score 1):

First style is better. Though you should use better variable name

Answer (score 0):

This is more readable and good practice too.

```
if(!status){
//do sth
}else{
//do sth
}
```

Comment: except I would flip the clauses you just test if (status)

Comment: Furthermore, you could reformulate the variable name with an "is-" prefix to indicate what the default value is.